# Find the cluster points of the set (0,1)∩ℚ

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I think every point in a closed interval [0,1] is cluster points of (0,1)∩ℚ. But I am not sure my answer is correct since (0,1) is not closed interval. Can anyone help me verify if my answer is correct? Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$\dfrac{1}{n}\to0$ and $1-\dfrac{1}{n}\to 1$